# Short story involving a crashing alien spacecraft and a blind girl

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this short story during the late 1980s to early 1990s in an English language collection.

An alien space ship is crashing to earth, with its crew terrified of their impending death.  Their only cargo, an alien creature, senses their terror and does what it can to ease their suffering telepathically.

The creature survives the crash, and is found by a blind girl - the creature gives the girl the ability to see for the first time ever, and demonstrates further abilities to the girls friends.

The story ends when the creature falls down a mine shaft, possibly while helping the girl and her friends save someone.  The girl can sense the creature falling and then its death.  The creature may have been deliberately knocked off the girls shoulder by a bully who is jealous of the girl now she has the creature.

Comment: Out of curiosity could that have been in the same collection as your two previous questions?

Comment: @Jenayah they certainly could have been, although I had several collections of sci-fi short stories in my childhood, with at least two of those books identified through previous questions here (and one outstanding).  I'm gradually identifying various collections I had in my childhood, so these three I posed today could have been in the same collection but equally they may not have.

Comment: @Jenayah I also remember one of these collections having a rendition of "The Fog Horn" by Ray Bradbury, but I have been unable to identify which collection - none of the works which list The Fog Horn as included match up with my recollection.

Comment: I've read this, it was in an anthology for children or at least young teenagers. Was the creature vaguely rabbit-shaped, but odd colours?

Comment: @DanielRoseman yup, that it was - seems we have both read the same story.